# How to enable scrollbar even though the controls inside are disabled

Tags: vb.net, winforms, infragistics

I have a form and inside the form I have an `UltraExpandableGroupBoxPanel` which holds some controls. Eg:

```
Me.UltraExpandableGroupBoxPanel.AutoScroll = True
Me.UltraExpandableGroupBoxPanel.Controls.Add(Me.ctlCars)
Me.UltraExpandableGroupBoxPanel.Controls.Add(Me.ctlPlanes)
Me.UltraExpandableGroupBoxPanel.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
Me.UltraExpandableGroupBoxPanel.Name = "UltraExpandableGroupBoxPanel"
Me.UltraExpandableGroupBoxPanel.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(500, 1000)
```

The `AutoScroll` property is set to `True` so it can show the scrollbar. When the two controls are disabled, the scrollbar is also disabled and I cannot move the scrollbar to view the information from the bottom on the form. Is there a way to enable the scrollbar even though the controls are disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making control disabled, try by making it read only and display control in grey color so that it looks similar to disabled mode.

Comment: If this answer is useful for you please mark it as answer.